# How to add multiple columns to a matrix when number of columns for that matrix is known in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a function to go over .csv files loaded as matrices (one by one as I use the function on them) that will add a 19th, 20th, 21st, 22nd, 23rd, and 24th column. These matrices will all have 18 columns, so I'm starting at column 19 so I don't erase any of the previous data. It should first prompt the data for the 19th and 22nd columns (as a numeric) and then compute the data for the rest of the columns. I keep getting the "new columns would leave holes after the existing columns" message.

I've tried switching from just trying to assign matrix[,19] to doing cbind(matrix, c("name of column 19", "name of column 20", etc.) and neither works.

```
func<- function(matrix){
  cbind(matrix, c("name19","name20", "name21", "name22", "name23", "name24"))
  matrix[,19] <- as.numeric(readline(prompt = "enter number ")) 
  matrix[,22] <- as.numeric(readline(prompt = "enter number "))
  matrix[x,20] <- 1.25*(matrix$colname10[x]/4) 
  matrix[x,21] <- matrix[x,20]/(15*matrix[x,19])
  matrix[x,23] <- 1.25*(matrix$colname13[x]/4) 
  matrix[x,24] <- matrix[x,23]/(15*matrix[x,22]) 
    }
func(matrixwith18cols)
```

This gives my error

Instead of adding new columns and doing the math on the observations I ask it to and adding new observations, I get

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , 22, value = 1) : 
  new columns would leave holes after existing columns
```

in the console (After I enter in 1 as both prompts)

Comment: We desperately need a [MCVE]. The error message strongly suggests you are not working with a matrix but rather have a dataframe.

Comment: Oh thank you! I thought my example was complete because I thought I was working with a matrix, but you're right it's a dataframe. I believe this was the main source of the issue I was having

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a matrix to add (here in your cbind, you are binding your matrix to a vector, I don't know how R would react to that).

Also, the output of your cbind function is not saved in the new matrix.
So what I would do:

```
mat.to.add = matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(matrix), ncol = 6)
marix = cbind(matrix, mat.to.add)
```

and then do your mathematical operations